# Option selecting named colours provided by the xcolor package

Tags: color

How can I include an option in a latex document that selects between

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
```

Perhaps I can put the capability in a style file.

Comment: Why select? Why not just `\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}` and enjoy access to all named colors?

Comment: Would any colour names conflict?

Comment: See [xcolor documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). All three sets are listed. It seems some names from dvipsnames and svgnames overlap. I read somewhere dvipsnames is based on CMYK model while svgnames and x11names are based on RGB. I am not sure how important it is for PDFs for reading on screen but you should be careful if you create PDFs for printing, and probably which CMYK should be used.

Comment: What happens if  I call a color with same name, one would override the other?

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. From the [xcolor documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf):

2.15.1 Name clashes between `dvipsnames` and `svgnames`
Due to the fixed option processing order (which does not depend on the order how the options were specified in the `\usepackage` command), the `svgnames` colors will always overrule `dvipsnames` colors with identical names. This can lead to undesired results if both options are used together. For instance, Fuchsia yields [image] under the regime of `dvipsnames` and [image] with respect to `svgnames`. However, there is a simple trick — based on deferred color definition — that allows us to use colors from both sets in the desired way:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Fuchsia}
```

Now all colors from the SVG set are available (except Fuchsia) plus Fuchsia from the other set.

Comment: Understood.  Because  `svgnames` always overrule `dvipsnames` you can defer `Fuchsia` from `dvipsnames`, which will then be made to overrule `svgnames` with the command `\definecolors{Fuchsia}`.

Comment: Seems that the only overlap in between `dvipsnames` and `svgnames`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to select if one uses

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
```

One can also defer the colour names from `dvipsnames` so they will not be overruled by the `svgnames` set.

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Fuchsia}
```